# How to present our browser's public certificates (self signed)?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl

I would like to make secure connections with the internet using my own self signed certificate.

I do not understand that if I want to make a  connection with www.google.com, how will it provide a public certificate(self signed) to my browser? Assuming my browser has installed self signed certificate as a trusted root CA.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  How would you be connecting to Google with your own certificate? Google's SSL cert is signed by a CA which your browser trusts. If you mean you want to add a self signed cert to your own website then you need to read up on setting up SSL certs. Users will see untrusted cert issues though and are unlikely to add your cert to their browsers.

Comment: Little more information would be nice. (Eg what browser you are using). Guide to adding trusted root CA for Firefox here https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:AddRootToFirefox

Comment: To have a secure connection with a website, it may  not be necessary for the website to know who you are. In that case (like for Google) you just need to trust the certificate that the website provided. So you should not be worried about your self signed certificate

Answer (score 2):

> make a connection with www.google.com, how will it provide a public certificate(self signed) to my browser?

You seem to be confused about how SSL/TLS works.

Google is maybe a bad example to choose - its a certificate authority who can issue certificates recognized by most browsers. So all its certificates are self-signed.

If you have created a client certificate, that has no impact on how google's service presents its certificates.

Your client certificate only has some relevance when you connect to a service which expects to see a client certificate. While widely used within and between organizations, I'm not aware of any public services using private certificates.

Unless you have some sort of relationship with the service provider and their service is specifically configured to handle client certificates, your certificate will be ignored.

As to the case where a provider has said that they expect, and can handle client certificates, it would be very unusual (i.e. incompetent) for them to invest any trust in a self-signed certificate unless

- you have made some provision to provide them with the public key of the certificate or the signing certificate via a secure channel,
- OR there a subsequent enrollment (e.g. making a payment) using the connection secured by the client certificate which then forms the basis of the trust

Comment: Google has their own CA, but it is subordinate to (and signed by) GeoTrust. Otherwise +2 if I could.